# How to create a separate table with two mapped fields?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a user entity. The user will have a list of friends. I have a problem with creating a batch to this mapped list. I want the board to look like this https://zapodaj.net/41cd4553308d3.png.html The first column is the user ID, and the second column is the friend's ID. I was thinking about doing it

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
        name = "users_friends",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
)
@Column(name = "user_friend_id")
private Set<UserEntity> friends;
```

But `ElementCollection` does not map the entity and this way goes away.

How can I create such a special table for mapping the user with a list of friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a many-to-many relationship.  JPA supports them no problem https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany

In your case doing

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name="users_friends",
  joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
  inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_friend_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
private List<UserEntity> friends;
```

Should do the trick